# Where does one set ExternalProject properties?

Tags: cmake

In the `ExternalProject_Add` documentation for cmake, it mentions setting the `EP_BASE` property. I've attempted setting this using the `set` keyword, however it doesn't seem to work.

How should this property be set for `ExternalProject_Add` to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EP_BASE` is the directory property. From [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html):

> Otherwise, if the EP_BASE **directory** property is set ...

You need to use [set_directory_properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_directory_properties.html) command to modify the value. For instance:

> set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EP_BASE "/path/to/directory")

Answer (score 1):

As this is a property you can set it using [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/set_property.html) with the `DIRECTORY` as the first argument.

```
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY EP_BASE "path/to/directory")
```